# Compiler version error

Tags: remix, compiler

I am following a YouTube tutorial and I have the following contract (in Remix):

```
 // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
 pragma solidity >= 0.6.0 < 0.9.0;
 import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
        
 contract FundMe {
            mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded; 
        }
```

The import part is in red and has the following error:

```
"@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol:2:1: ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.6.0+commit.26b70077.Emscripten.clang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
^---------------------^
.deps/npm/@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol
@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol
SourceUnit
@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol 1:0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

replace

```
pragma solidity >= 0.6.0 < 0.9.0;
```

with

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
```

NOTE: You can change the compiler version in remix (So you use 0.8.0)

Here is the screenshot of where to change compiler version[image: switch compiler version]

Comment: Hello, I replaced with pragma solidity ^0.8.0; and I go the error contracts/FundMe.sol:2:1: ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.6.0+commit.26b70077.Emscripten.clang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity = 0.8.0;
^----------------------^
PragmaDirective
contracts/FundMe.sol 1:0

Comment: How do you change the compiler version?

Comment: @DJQuimoso I added a screenshot that shows how to change the compiler versions in Remix

Comment: @DJQuimoso could you please accept and upvote the answer then? Much appreciated.

Comment: When I try to upvote I get the error "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded."

Comment: @DJQuimoso Not an issue, glad I was able to help. If you can accept the answer, that would be splendid. If not, don't beat yourself over it. its all good :D